# How to use Namespaces of .Net in C++?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

How do I make use of the .NET framework namespaces from C++?

Comment: learn to provide more information when you post a question... Contacting emergency services with just 'help! I am in trouble' is just a waste of time. What is your specific problem? Do you want to use a managed type/class in managed C++ or unmanaged C++ ?

Comment: Bah, there is nothing wrong with this. The question is pretty obvious. He wants to reference .NET namespaces from Visual C++.

Comment: Clean up text and tags (not a C# question at all)

Answer (score 5):

### C# will be

```
using System;

using System.Configuration;
```

### C++ will be

```
using namespace System;

using namespace System::Configuration;
```

---

Don't forget to reference the libraries in your C++ project properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in managed C++. Use #using directive and use the namespaces like you normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Start Here: [Pure C++: Hello, C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx)

Comment: The link is broken.