# 'System' is not a namespace-name

Tags: c++, namespaces, build-error

I am tying to use some .Net namespaces in my c++ code. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736786/how-to-use-namespaces-of-net-in-c) I have found, how can I do that. In my code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::Sql;
using namespace Microsoft::Sqlserver::Server;
using namespace System::Data::SqlTypes;

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I run it I get these errors:

```
0:08:06: Running steps for project Test...
10:08:06: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:08:06: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../Test -I../Test -I. -o main.o ../Test/main.cpp
../Test/main.cpp:2:17: error: 'System' is not a namespace-name
../Test/main.cpp:2:23: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
../Test/main.cpp:3:17: error: 'System' has not been declared
../Test/main.cpp:3:25: error: 'Data' is not a namespace-name
../Test/main.cpp:3:29: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
../Test/main.cpp:4:17: error: 'System' has not been declared
../Test/main.cpp:4:31: error: 'Sql' is not a namespace-name
../Test/main.cpp:4:34: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
../Test/main.cpp:5:17: error: 'Microsoft' has not been declared
../Test/main.cpp:5:39: error: 'Server' is not a namespace-name
../Test/main.cpp:5:45: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
../Test/main.cpp:6:17: error: 'System' has not been declared
../Test/main.cpp:6:31: error: 'SqlTypes' is not a namespace-name
../Test/main.cpp:6:39: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
10:08:06: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Test (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
10:08:06: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

what should I do to solve this problem? 
By the way, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732789/system-a-namespace-with-this-name-does-not-exist) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763179/error-c2653-system-is-not-a-class-or-a-namespace-name-in-form-header-file-vi) posts, but I could not understand, what should I do with /clr in my cpp code?

Comment: This is not a c++ code, it's a C++/CLI and you need to compile it with different command line arguments.

Comment: C++ and C++/CLI are different languages. You're using GCC, which does not have a C++/CLI compiler.

Comment: Oh, wait, it's not even Visual C++ compiler, GCC won't ever comile this

Comment: You're very unlikely to be able to use C++/CLI on Linux.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is Mono a C#-only environement? I though it is a CLI replacement.